# Mysql custom post types

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using WpDataTables for `Wordpress plugin`. However, this is general `mySQL Query` and it works fine until this point.

```
SELECT posts_apex_po.ID AS apex_po_ID,
posts_apex_po.post_title AS apex_po_post_title,
posts_apex_po_payment.ID AS apex_po_payment_ID,
posts_apex_po_payment.post_title AS apex_po_payment_post_title
FROM wp_posts AS posts_apex_po, wp_posts AS posts_apex_po_payment
WHERE 1=1 
AND posts_apex_po.post_status = 'publish'
AND posts_apex_po.post_type = 'apex_po'
AND posts_apex_po_payment.post_status = 'publish'
AND posts_apex_po_payment.post_type = 'apex_po_payment'
```

The problem is that when I try to get post meta values of `apex_po` or `apex_po_payment` custom post types, it does not work.

`apex_po_payment` has a meta key `apex_po_meta.purchase_order` which has value of `apex_po ID`

So basically `Apex_PO` is a purchase order and when you create a payment using `apex_po_payment`, you select a `apex_po ID` to link it ito.

I am trying to display the linked `PO & PO Payment` but its not working.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out on my own after a little search here n there and making sense of mysql join queries. I had to make two separate queries on each custom post type in same mysql table and then left join them on the field I wanted.

Posting answer for any one that come across the same issue in future.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
    posts_apex_po.ID AS apex_po_id,
    posts_apex_po.post_title AS apex_po_post_title,
    apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl.meta_value AS apex_po_meta_grand_total,

FROM wp_posts AS posts_apex_po
  INNER JOIN (SELECT apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl_posts.ID as id, meta_value, meta_key  FROM wp_postmeta AS apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl_postmeta  INNER JOIN wp_posts AS apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl_posts   ON apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl_postmeta.post_id = apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl_posts.ID   AND apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl_posts.post_type = 'apex_po') AS apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl
     ON apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl.meta_key = 'grand_total' AND apex_po_meta_grand_total_tbl.id = posts_apex_po.ID 
WHERE 1=1 
   AND posts_apex_po.post_status = 'publish'
   AND posts_apex_po.post_type = 'apex_po' ) x

LEFT JOIN

( SELECT posts_apex_po_payment.post_date AS apex_po_payment_post_date,
       posts_apex_po_payment.post_title AS apex_po_payment_post_title,
       apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl.meta_value AS apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid,
       apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl.meta_value AS apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order
FROM wp_posts AS posts_apex_po_payment
  INNER JOIN (SELECT apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl_posts.ID as id, meta_value, meta_key  FROM wp_postmeta AS apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl_postmeta  INNER JOIN wp_posts AS apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl_posts   ON apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl_postmeta.post_id = apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl_posts.ID   AND apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl_posts.post_type = 'apex_po_payment') AS apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl
     ON apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl.meta_key = 'amount_paid' AND apex_po_payment_meta_amount_paid_tbl.id = posts_apex_po_payment.ID 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl_posts.ID as id, meta_value, meta_key  FROM wp_postmeta AS apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl_postmeta  INNER JOIN wp_posts AS apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl_posts   ON apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl_postmeta.post_id = apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl_posts.ID   AND apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl_posts.post_type = 'apex_po_payment') AS apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl
     ON apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl.meta_key = 'purchase_order' AND apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order_tbl.id = posts_apex_po_payment.ID 
WHERE 1=1 
   AND posts_apex_po_payment.post_status = 'publish'
   AND posts_apex_po_payment.post_type = 'apex_po_payment' ) y
ON  y.apex_po_payment_meta_purchase_order = x.apex_po_id
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your mentioned query you are trying to get a post having two post types at same time.

```
AND posts_apex_po.post_type = 'apex_po'
AND posts_apex_po_payment.post_type = 'apex_po_payment'
```

Its not possible that a single post have two different post types at same time, so you should OR in between that.

Comment: That's not my problem at the moment. I have results when I run that query and I am actually querying two custom post types and it works fine so far. 

Its just that when I link first custom post type to second custom post type using meta key... it stops working

Plus I can not get any meta key / meta values out of either custom post types using the above.